# TCP retransmissions when we rapidly open multiple connections to the same host

Tags: tcp, troubleshooting, packet-analysis

We are experiencing a retransmission issue on some of our computers on our LAN, when connecting to external hosts. I first started trying to trace the issue when the `npm typings install` command was timing out on some connections to https://api.typings.org/

The first two or three connections would return quickly, but subsequent connections would see a 3 second or 9 second connection delay, or timeout and fail. But this behaviour differed on different machines on the network. We are running Windows 10 throughout our client machines. Some computers would start seeing delayed connections after 3 or 4 successful connections. However, some would only start seeing delays after 9 or 10 connections. A couple of computers showed no delays at all.

I initially added some diagnostic logging to the `typings install` command to try and see if the issue was with node or typings, or api.typings.org, as unlikely as that seemed. The logging just listed the attempted connections and showed the elapsed time. You can see the timing increasing:

```
> ....@1.0.0 typings C:\....
> typings "install"

  popsicle https://api.typings.org/entries/dt/zone.js/tags/0.0.0%2B20160316155526 +0ms
  popsicle https://api.typings.org/entries/dt/es6-promise/tags/0.0.0%2B20160423074304 +3s
  popsicle https://api.typings.org/entries/dt/es6-collections/tags/0.5.1%2B20160316155526 +6s
  popsicle https://api.typings.org/entries/dt/node/tags/6.0.0%2B20160514165920 +11s
typings ERR! message Unable to connect to "https://api.typings.org/entries/dt/node/tags/6.0.0%2B20160514165920"
typings ERR! caused by connect ETIMEDOUT 104.24.113.177:443

typings ERR! cwd C:\....
typings ERR! system Windows_NT 10.0.10586
typings ERR! command "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\....\\node_modules\\typings\\dist\\bin.js" "install"
typings ERR! node -v v4.4.4
typings ERR! typings -v 0.8.1
typings ERR! code EUNAVAILABLE

typings ERR! If you need help, you may report this error at:
typings ERR!   <https://github.com/typings/typings/issues>
```

This was inconclusive, so I tried watching the connections with Wireshark, and at this point was able to correlate those delays to TCP retransmissions. I subsequently was able to reproduce the behaviour with a trivial program written in Delphi that opened multiple HTTP or HTTPS connections to any site outside our LAN, as near to simultaneously as possible (using multiple threads).

The Wireshark trace (online at: https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/4943090/retransmission.pcap, 38kb) shows 3 connections out of 11 succeeding quickly, but the other 8 retransmitting after 3 seconds. Then only the last one of those retransmissions succeeds, and another 6 seconds later, the 7 remaining connections retransmit again, and again, only the last one succeeds. After this the client app gives up, but I am presuming, the pattern would continue with longer timeouts until all the connections completed.

[image: Start of connection attempts]

First batch of retransmissions after 3 seconds:

[image: First batch of retransmissions]

Second batch of retransmissions after another 6 seconds:

[image: Second batch of retransmissions]

I extended the test app to attempt as many as 100 simultaneous connections, and the computers that did not exhibit the problem for smaller batches also completed these without retransmissions.

Some more detail on the network:

1. Gigabit network internally, 100/40mbit fibre connection externally.
2. NAT through Watchguard XTM-25 firewall.
3. 24 port Linksys SRW2024P 1Gbit switch.
4. Windows 10 clients, 10.0.10586 - 10.0.14342, Windows Server 2012 servers

I've run a bunch of tests on various computers on the network. Some I was able to reconfigure to try various network options. Most of the desktops and all the servers are plugged into ports on the Linksys 1Gbit switch.

The 100mbit, 1GB and Wireless columns reflect the approximate number of connections that did not experience retransmissions in a given batch of connections. That is, if I attempted 10 simultaneous connections on a machine with 80% success, 8 of them would complete without retransmission. If I attempted 20, about 16 would complete without retranmission. The number of successful connections varied but would average at the percentages shown.

```
Computer     Wired Adapter                                100mbit  1GB  Wireless Adapter                        Wireless
========     =============                                =======  ===  ================                        ========
Desktop#1    Intel(R) Ethernet Connection I217-LM         100%     40%
Desktop#2    Realtek PCIe GBE Family Controller 1/10/2015 100%     80%  Dell Wireless 1703 802.11b/g/n (2.4GHz) 100%
Desktop#3    Intel(R) Ethernet Connection I219-V          100%     40%  Dell Wireless 1801 802.11bgn            100%
Server#1     Broadcom BCM5716C NetXtreme II GigE                  100%
Server#2     Broadcom NetXtreme Gigabit Ethernet                  100%
Notebook#1                                                              Broadcom 802.11ac Network Adapter       100%
Desktop#4    Realtek PCIe GBE Family Controller 5/04/2015 100%    100%
Desktop#5    Realtek PCIe GBE Family Controller                    80%
```

On Desktop#1, I have tried many different network adapter options. Note that when we switched the desktops to 100mbit, they never experienced retransmissions.

I plugged Desktop#4 into Desktop#1's port, and confirmed that the problem isn't with that specific port.

I have rebooted the firewall and switch to make sure there wasn't a transient issue there.

There does not appear to be any issue connecting to internal hosts, only to those external to our LAN. The connections do not all need to be to the same host, but the issue definitely seems to affect a higher proportion of packets when connecting to a single host. Have only tested with HTTP and HTTPS.

Any ideas?

### Updated with additional config detail

- The network has a simple topology: all hosts connected to a 24 port Linksys SRW2024P 1Gbit switch (no configuration required).
- The WatchGuard XTM-25 LAN port is also connected to the same switch, and WAN port (also connecting at gigabit) connects to an Australian NBN fibre endpoint router (not sure of the model of this device; it's enclosed and not very accessible, no user-configurable options). The NBN connection is 100/40mbit.
- The wireless traffic goes through a Netgear WNR1000 802.11abn router, connected directly to the WatchGuard on a separate port.
- All outgoing traffic is configured through a 1-1 NAT + Dynamic NAT firewall policy with no QoS or rate limiting configured; apart from that, there are additional firewall rules that I don't think are relevant. The WatchGuard has a pretty straightforward configuration without a lot changed from factory defaults.
- Network adapters are entirely factory default settings; I have tried tweaking every accessible settings on the adapter on Desktop#1 without effect - only reducing the speed to 100mbit made any difference.

Comment: You are going to need to provide more information. How is the network connected, what models are the network devices, and what are the configurations of the network devices? Edit your question to include this, and any other relevant information, e.g. logs.

Comment: I've added some additional detail, but not quite sure what else you are looking for. pcap already included, and we don't have any other logs that shed light on the issue as yet. Most of the network device models were already included.

Comment: The Netgear router is a consumer-grade device, which is off-topic here, as are the network adapters and configurations of your end-devices. We really need to look at the device configurations, and you really, really need to keep firewall logs, which may shed a lot of light on the situation. The switch logs and interface statistics could prove valuable, too. Unless you can provide more information, we are simply left with opinion-based guesses, and that is off-topic.

Comment: Something upstream of your devices is occasionally dropping the initial SYN packets from your devices or the SYN/ACK response is getting dropped on the return journey. The fact that **only** TCP handshake packets are being retransmitted strongly smells like either some kind of policy issue on the Firewall or b) a misbehaving server, however if you are experiencing this issue on multiple websites, you can pretty much rule out b. You need to check the firewall, enable logging and follow the TCP handshake, if you see the SYN packets arriving from the problematic clients but don't see the SYN bein

Comment: @MarkoPolo, thank you, that's helpful - we are logging traffic on the firewall and have eliminated a number of other devices from the issue, there does seem to be something up with the firewall, so are also talking to the firewall vendor.